# How to close a connection in jsp page

Tags: jsp

i am using jsp in that i am creating a db connection and i want to close the connection now.plz help me with that
this is my code

```
<%
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

System.out.println("driver loaded");
System.out.println("Driver is loaded");
Connection con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/charms1?user=root&password=root");
System.out.println("Connection created");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from equip_master");
%>

  <table class="main" align="center" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="did">Equipment Id</td>
    <td class="dname">Equipment Name</td>
  </tr>
  </table>

  <div class="overflow1">
  <table class="main scroll1" align="center" border="1">
  <% while (rs.next()) {%>
  <tr onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true);" onmouseout="ChangeColor(this, false);" onclick="DoNav('<%=rs.getString("equp_id") %>');">
    <td class="did"><%=rs.getString("equp_id") %></td>
    <td class="dname1"><%=rs.getString("equp_name")%></td>

 </tr>
  <%}
  %>
 </table>
 </div>
```

Comment: take the answer i have provided....and remove ur answer before u get downvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put all your related database code in a try block and add this to it

```
   <%    
Connection con=null;
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

System.out.println("driver loaded");
System.out.println("Driver is loaded");
 con= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/charms1?user=root&password=root");
System.out.println("Connection created");
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from equip_master");
%>

  <table class="main" align="center" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="did">Equipment Id</td>
    <td class="dname">Equipment Name</td>
  </tr>
  </table>

  <div class="overflow1">
  <table class="main scroll1" align="center" border="1">
  <% while (rs.next()) {%>
  <tr onmouseover="ChangeColor(this, true);" onmouseout="ChangeColor(this, false);" onclick="DoNav('<%=rs.getString("equp_id") %>');">
    <td class="did"><%=rs.getString("equp_id") %></td>
    <td class="dname1"><%=rs.getString("equp_name")%></td>

 </tr>
  <%}
  %>
 </table>
 </div>

<%} catch (SQLException ex) {
                String message = "ERROR: " + ex.getMessage();
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (con != null) {
                    // closes the database connection
                    try {
                        con.close();
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }}%>
```

message here is a String which can be passed as a reponse to another page.For example its uploaded or some error will be displayed incase there is one..